# how to vary violin width in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

Selecting 'scale = "count"' inside 'geom_violin' makes the areas of the violins scaled proportionally to the number of observations.

However, when using facet_wrap, the width is scaled for each facet, not globally (i.e. relating to all facets). This is in contrast to the equivalent in geom_boxplot where 'varwidth = TRUE' makes scales widths accounting for all the facets.

Is there a way to make the width of the violins scale accounting for all the facets?

Comment: I am not sure, I have never used "tidyverse" which that answer is based on, so I don't follow it. I am wondering if there is a way of choosing this within ggplots; it is strange that violins and boxplots have opposite behaviours

Comment: ggplot2 is a part of the tidyverse https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/ and the answer provided clearly uses ggplot2.